# Is possible to scroll an UITabBar?

Tags: iphone, c++, uitabbar

I've downloaded an Download Manager from App Store and noticed that the app scrolls an UITabBar,like: When the user press a button the bar walks left and show other option to the user.Is that really possible and does Apple accept these type of customization in UITabBar?If it's possible how can i do that,please provide some sample code or reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, possible. but not using usual `UITabbar`. you have to create custom tabbar that behave the same. there are projects out there that you can use, save a lot of time of your work.

**[infinitetabbar](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/InfiniTabBar)** : A scrolling tab bar with space for infinite items

**[jsscrollabletabbar](https://github.com/jasarien/JSScrollableTabBar)** : JSScrollableTabBar is a simple, refined tab bar UI control that resembles the TabStrip found in the popular Three20 library but without any of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a custom-made control (a scroll view with a few child buttons). It's perfectly acceptable at the Store if you don't use any undocumented functions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can implement scrollable tabbar using `UITabBar`.
Adobe writer maybe thought about using only `UITabBar`, so he mentioned it can't be implemented, but if you use `ScrollView` and `UITabBar`, it can be implemented.
Put `tabbar` on `scrollview`, `scrollview` size is 320,460 (it excludes status bar size).
TabBar size is any size you want, `scrollview` `contentsize` must be equal to `tabbar` size.