# Xcode - Sliding Tab Bar?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard, tabbar

Is there a tutorial I am overlooking online for a sliding tab bar application? I've been going at this research for little over a week. I'm wanting to use this feature instead of having the "more" tabs on the main screen. The iOS "Thousand Foot Krutch" app has this feature, so I know Apple does allow this kind of feature.

If there isn't one online, is someone able to explain to me how I can go at making one? I do use Storyboard (lightly) if that is an advantage/disadvantage. I mostly code out details in the view controllers .m file, but for storyboard I use a physical view controller, D&D some details as I follow tutorials online (Ray Wenderlich, Geeky Lemon).

My layout is simple: "UITabController >> UINavigationController >> ViewController".

Thank you everyone!
-TG52

Comment: have you tried putting the actual tab bar on a scroll view and just making its frame width a lot bigger?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9643154/894671

Comment: Jsdodgers, my experience with Xcode is little over a year. I've picked up a ton, but I didn't realize you could put a TabBar into a ScrollView. (Which does now make sense, it scrolls.)

GuntisTreulands, Thank you very much, this answered my question! Does Apple accept applications with a mimic UITabBar like that? I've read online they could be rejected. (Based on code?)

Thank you both very much!